# Изменение href у ссылок

Tags: php

Есть текст, в нем есть тег ссылки, нужно изменить аттрибут href, добавив к началу адреса "/". Если слеш есть, то добавлять не надо. Можно ли это сделать средствами регулярных выражений или как либо еще. Javascript - решение не нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного короче регулярка, работает так же..

```
preg_replace('/(href=")([^\/]+")/i', '$1/$2' , $s);
```

Comment: Ошибаетесь, не так же работает. =)
Мой вариант ошибочен, т.к. при замене отгрызает первый символ во вторых запоминающих скобках.

Comment: Спасибо, идеально! =)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
preg_replace('/(href=")[^\/](.+")/i', '$1/$2' , $s);
```

где $s ваши строковые данные для поиска и замены.

Comment: ну все равно почти) спасибо